# PHP Caching or Session issue

Tags: php

I have a php/mysql application i created... Here is a scenario of the problem I'm having

- Log on with user1
- Directed to user1 secured page
- Logout with user1
- Logon with user2
- Directed to user2 secured page
- Click the browser back button and I'm in user1 securedpage with user2 logged in

I'm more thinking this is a caching issue or session issue. Can anyone please help

Comment: You need to post code, that's how it works here :)

Comment: Is the URL for the user1 secured page different than for the user2 secure page? Are you checking in the code that each user can only load the page intended for them?

Comment: yes the url is different for both users.

Comment: Kareem you have only answered the first of the questions @Eli asked. You need to answer the second one too.

Comment: I have a user check in my usercheck login process that directs the users to their respective secured page.

Comment: //register username

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

//Check username type
if (row['username'] == "staff"){
 header("Location: staff secured page");
}
else{
 header("Location: student secured page");
}

Comment: You need to do more then check on the login, you need to make sure that a student can't access the staff page even if they type in the url directly!

Comment: Eli should I write a code directly on the secured pages that prevents a student user from accessing the page directly and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a million Eli it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your browser has simply cached the page. Use this at the top of the page:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Comment: Should i put the headers on each of the pages

Comment: Only the pages you don't want to be cached by the browser, they also have to come before you output any content.

Comment: Thanks Matthew I'm going to try it and i will get back to you.